¿Como dar efecto a un intro de página para mostrar su contenido?
Estoy creando una página en el cual tenga un intro de bienvenida, que al dar clic ya sea en el botón o cualquier parte que tenga el efecto de ocultarse los dos div uno hacia arriba y el otro hacia abajo y de esa manera mostrar el contenido.


.sobre{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110%;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sobre .first{
  background-color: #fff0cf;
  border-bottom: #b49b50 solid 1px; 
}

.sobre .second{
  background-color: #fff0cf;
  border-top: #b49b50 solid 1px; 
}

.sobre .first{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sobre .second{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sobre button{
  z-index: 2;
    border: none;
   border-radius: 50%;
   font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}


.sello{
  font-size: 16px;
  
}

.sello{
  background: #917407;
  border: none;
  color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: -6px -6px 14px rgba(255, 192, 192, 0.7), -6px -6px 10px rgba(255, 193, 193, 0.5), 6px 6px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, .075), 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: 2s booms infinite;
  
}


@keyframes booms {
  0% {
      transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  50% {
      transform: scale(1.1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  100% {
      transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

/*Estilos con animation contorno respirando*/
@keyframes breathe {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(27, 29, 28, 0.699);
  }
  70% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(37, 211, 102, 0);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}


/*Estilos de animacion del icono latiendo*/
@keyframes beat {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
<div id="sobre" class="sobre">
      <div id="sobre_hoja1" class="first"></div>
        <button id="sello" class="sello">Ver Contenido</button>
      <div id="sobre_hoja2" class="second"></div>
    </div>




Para hacer que un botón se dispare como si fuera una carta y se abra de arriba a abajo, podríamos cambiar algo en tu código. Primero usar un label como botón y un checkbox oculto que activa la animación y oculta el botón visible cuando se marca. También agregar transition: transform 0.5s ease; para que haga el efecto de la carta abriéndose: puedes cambiarle los segundos si quieres que el efecto sea más lento o más rápido.


.sobre{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110%;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sobre .first{
  background-color: #fff0cf;
  border-bottom: #b49b50 solid 1px; 
  transition: transform 0.5s ease; /* Transición suave al cambiar transform */
}

.sobre .second{
  background-color: #fff0cf;
  border-top: #b49b50 solid 1px;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease; /* Transición suave al cambiar transform */
}

.sobre .first{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sobre .second{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sobre button{
  z-index: 2;
    border: none;
   border-radius: 50%;
   font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}


.sello{
  font-size: 16px;
  
}

.sello{
  background: #917407;
  border: none;
  color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: -6px -6px 14px rgba(255, 192, 192, 0.7), -6px -6px 10px rgba(255, 193, 193, 0.5), 6px 6px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, .075), 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: 2s booms infinite;
  z-index: 2;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  display: flex; /* Centrado del contenido */
  align-items: center; /* Centra verticalmente el contenido */
  justify-content: center; /* Centra horizontalmente el contenido */
}


@keyframes booms {
  0% {
      transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  50% {
      transform: scale(1.1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  100% {
      transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

/*Estilos con animation contorno respirando*/
@keyframes breathe {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(27, 29, 28, 0.699);
  }
  70% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(37, 211, 102, 0);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}


/*Estilos de animacion del icono latiendo*/
@keyframes beat {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

/* Ocultar checkbox */
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

/* Animaciones al marcar el checkbox */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .first {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .second {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .sello {
  display: none;
}
<div id="sobre" class="sobre">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <div id="sobre_hoja1" class="first"></div>
  <label for="toggle" class="sello">Ver Contenido</label>
  <div id="sobre_hoja2" class="second"></div>
</div>




Muchas gracias por tu aportación fue de gran utilidad.
